# How to find how many number of transactions are happening in SQL Server/SQL Server database in a day?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, windows-server

I have to migrate my SQL Server on a particular public cloud, which is charging/licensing on the basis of number of transactions happening on the SQL Server.

I am aware of the Performance Counters for SQL Server:Databases - Transactions/Sec AND Batches/Sec.

Do I simply convert these transactions per second data to hours, or is there some other method to find out total number of transactions going on in SQL Server.

Comment: Are they charging per actual database transaction? This seems odd as a database transaction is not a specific unit of work. It could be 1 ms of CPU time and a few bytes of data or it could be hours of CPU time and GB of data in a single transaction.

Comment: That's like having a taxi that charges the same for 1km as for 3000km! `BEGIN SELECT 1; COMMIT;` is a transaction as could be `INSERT`ing several GB!

Comment: I am not sure about the costing part, but what I was asked is to find out is total number of transactions on the server per day basis. I have found this on Microsoft Forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a227fcbe-dc3c-4678-9723-74dd8116254c/sql-script-for-total-daily-transaction?forum=sqldataaccess. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Are you sure that they aren't referring to Storage Transactions? (IO operations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Perfmon counters for Transactions/Sec and Batch Requests/Sec are cumulative counters, meaning they keep going up after the SQL Server starts up.

**To get a count per day since startup**, divide the counter output by the number of days that the server has been up. An easy way to do that is to check the creation date of TempDB - here's an example query, but keep in mind that rounding will be a problem if the server's been up for less than a day or two:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, create_date, GETDATE()) 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = 2;
```

**To get daily numbers going forward**, consider saving the contents of that counter to a table. Then you can take a day's metric, subtract the day before, and you'll get the counter delta for that one day. (I use [sp_BlitzFirst and the Power BI Dashboard for DBAs](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/) to do this with 15-minute granularity. (Disclaimer: those are open source tools that I wrote.))

Unfortunately, if you try to do daily sampling, it can be inaccurate due to:

- The server restarting or clustered SQL Server service failing over
- The Availability Group or database mirror transitioning roles (failing over) does not reset those counters, but you'll need to add up the transactions or batches from both replicas
- If you're combining metrics from multiple replicas, keep in mind that you've also probably got monitoring software, and the monitoring software's queries are also going to be counted